# Database error Duplicate entry

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-db

So i have this error when i have duplicate values while inserting data, now my query is correct, i've tried to run it in phpmyadmin, and works just fine, but kohana gives me errors, this is how my query looks like:

```
DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `views` ( user_id, viewer_id, username, picture, view_time, view_count) 
                    VALUES ("'.$this->request->param('id2').'", "'.$user->id.'", "'.$user->username.'", "'.$user->picture.'", '.DB::expr('NOW()').', "1")
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `view_time` = NOW(), `view_count` = view_count +1
```

And in pure sql:

```
INSERT INTO `views` ( user_id, viewer_id, username, picture, view_time, view_count )
VALUES (
"134173", "139173", "username", "pic.jpg", NOW( ) , "1"
) ON DUPLICATE
KEY UPDATE `view_time` = NOW( ) ,
`view_count` = view_count +1
```

So basicly i try to insert and on duplicate values i update, but for some reason kohana gives me error:

```
kohana Database_Exception [ 1062 ]: Duplicate entry
```

How can i remove this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try this approach by not specifying the query type:

```php
$query = " 
  INSERT INTO `views` (user_id, viewer_id, username, picture, view_time, view_count)
  VALUES (%d, %d, '%s', '%s', %s, %d)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `view_time` = %s, `view_count` = view_count + 1";

$query = sprintf($query, $this->request->param('id2'), $user->id, $user->username, $user->picture, DB::expr('NOW()'), 1, DB::expr('NOW()'));

$result = Database::instance()->query(NULL, $query);
```